# If I don't mention any brand, am I allowed to contrast two laptops with just specs?

Tags: discussion, support

Basically, I want to ask whether it's worth it to get 200MHz less lock speed and 1MB less cache and 180 pixels less vertical resolution if it means to get the most reliable SSD in the market instead of a noname brand.

Is this allowed? (I know product recommendations are frowned upon but what if I don't mention any brand at all?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You're still asking *us* to decide for *you* how a few very minor differences in specifications will affect which computer is better for *you*.

Only you know what computer works best for you. Furthermore, the question will be too localized, because not only will it only apply to you, but the specifications you mention are so narrow that there is little or no chance of it ever being useful to anyone in the future.

For more insight into our recommendations policy, and for an explanation of what an acceptable shopping-related question might look like, [check out this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: The "you" is not as ambiguous if I specify what my usage patterns are. Furthermore, it might be generalizable into the future when *relative* performance is addressed (+10% more performance across benchmarks, 0.2% SSD failure rate instead of 2.2% [that data is available from a major french retailed and carefully documented with statistics])

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn regardless of how you word it, the question is way too specific to you, and yet way too unspecific on the needs. There is no way to quantify whether it is theoretically worth it to you personally to have a faster CPU or a more reliable SSD. We literally cannot answer that question for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is still essentially a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and would be considered unhelpful on most stack exchange sites.

The essential problem with this kind of advice is that it inevitably goes our of date far too quickly. They are localised in time, space and situation and any answers you might get would be very unlikely to be of use to other visitors in the future.

Essentially this question boils down to four separate questions and the relative importance of each:

- Is a 200MHz clock speed difference significant for my usage patterns?
- Is a 1MB less cache significant for my patterns?
- Would a 180 pixel taller screen be significant for my patterns?
- Is a noname brand of SSD significantly less reliable than a *reliable* brand?

None of these questions individually are a particularly good fit for a Stack exchange, and lumping them together would make them even less constructive, not more constructive.

Comment: My comment to nhinkle also applied to this post.